# COUNT(*) и mysql_num_rows

Tags: count, mysql

Чем отличается такой запрос:

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as `count` FROM `tasks`");
$d = mysql_fetch_array($q);

echo $d['count']; // количество записей
```

от такого запроса:

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `tasks`");
$n = mysql_num_rows($q);

echo $n; // количество записей
```

?

Может производительностью или чем?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый по производительности должен быть лучше,т.к. передача в php идёт лишь одно значение,а в последнем варианте вы весь массив данных передаёте,который не используете.

Comment: но если вы все эти данные будете использовать,то правильнее использовать вторую конструкцию

Comment: по крайне мере скорость вы заметите если будете подключаться через odbc))через стандартный драйвер при небольшом количестве записей будет особо не заметно

Comment: count(*) что означает?

Comment: сосчитать все строки в таблице

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp